# Adding features to my android project

Tags: android

I am new to android, and I started a project in android studio.
I found an interesting animation, which I would like to use, and perhaps edit in my project, it can be found here https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid

Now I wonder, how can I use this? I find the description on github hard to understand, I know that AS uses gradle to build, but where in the gradle file should I add the compile? And should I download some additional java files? And should I change my xml files?

I tried searching SO for answers, but one of the most relevant answers was about downloading a jar file, but there is no jar file to download in this case!

Thanx in advance.

Comment: *Now I wonder, how can I use this?*  Had you look at the demo project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the compile line to your module gradle (under the mobile app folder) dependency section, something like this (ordering of the dependencies doesn't matter)

```
dependencies {
    ... other stuff may be here
    compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
}
```

This will automatically download the java jar files required when you build.

Then where you want to use the pulsar control just add it to your activity xml file as specified in the projects readme under the usage section.

Comment: There are two gradle files, which one should I use?

Comment: @Rodbjartson Module gradle

Comment: I am sorry for asking so many stupid questions. I have added it to the module gradle file, but what now? Under the readme it says "In layout", and then a bunch of xml code. Should I put it under activity_main or content_main xml? And what about the manifest file? Thanks again guys

Comment: Sounds like you're using fragments, which is a default structure in Android Studio. The content_main should contain all the controls, so add it to that, within the top level xml layout.
See the sample xml for a hint
https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid/blob/master/demo/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: Hats off to you Sir, thank you so much. I believe this answer will help many people!

Answer (score 0):

Add `compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'` this in your app level gradle file

Comment: 1. Is that all? 2. Does it matter on what line?

Comment: you should add it inside dependencies block of app gradle, this will automatically insert the jar file to your project